# To find $x$ in $x^2 -8x-11=0$

Tags: quadratics

$x^2 -8x-11=0$

I have tried factorising but it won't factorise into a quadratic equation

Hi,
It would be great if you could complete this question with working and post it.
Thx

The two solutions of $x^2 -8x -11=0$ are in the form $x=p +\- Q root 3$ where p and q are both intergers. Find p and q. –  Jason 2 mins ago   edit   delete

That's the full question,

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: The two solutions of x^2 -8x -11=0 are in the form x=p +\- Q root 3, where p and q are both intergers. Find p and q.

Comment: That's the full question,

Comment: And no I don't think I know the quadratic formula

Comment: There are two solutions posted, one uses "completing the square" and the other uses the "quadratic formula".  Take your pick.

Answer (score 4):

$a=1$, $b=-8$, $c=-11$.  The quadratic formula says the roots are
$$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$=\frac{8\pm\sqrt{64+44}}{2}$$
$$=4\pm\frac12\sqrt{108}$$
$$=4\pm\frac12\sqrt{36\cdot3}$$
$$=4\pm3\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: To be symmetric: I'll upvote this answer. :-)

Comment: @KolaB. Thank you, wasn't fishing for it, but appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: (Without any knowledge about quadratic formula):
$$
x^2−8x−11=(x-4)^2-11-16=(x-4)^2-\sqrt{27}^2.
$$

Comment: Complete the square, yes.  I'll upvote this answer